# Access Damp over LAN

Tags: installation

I have installed Drupal. I followed a tutorial in Lynda.com that uses Acquia Dev Desktop, and then the core Drupal inside. (http://www.lynda.com/tutorials/73655-2.html)

I'm not sure if it is the best way to install Drupal. Anyway, it works. But now I need to access to the web from another laptop that is in another room. I can't.

When I see the web in the original mac, I have: `http://nameofproject:8082/`

From a second mac, to access to the Drupal web installed, I tried and it doesn't work:

- `http://IPnumber:8082/`(This drives me to the generic Acquia Drupal site)
- `http://IPnumber:8082/nameofproject`
- `http://IPnumber/nameofproject:8082/`
- `http://IPnumber/nameofproject/`

Comment: You can't access the site with just http://IPnumber:8082? Also make sure that your router's port forwarding settings are set to allow that port open.

Comment: With iPnumber:8082 in the guess mac I go to the same place that I go when I write 
http://localhost:8082/ in the mac that has the Drupal. This is a generic Acquia Drupal wellcome site. So I suppose the router allow that port? What I need is to acces to the Drupal site inside.

Comment: Ok if your getting the Acquia page then your router settings are fine. Try IPnumber:8082/nameWeb

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web server installed on your local network, and you type the IP address in the URL (e.g. IPaddress:port/nameofproject), you should get your Drupal site.
The fact that when you just type the IP, and the port you get the default server page means that your router settings are already working.

Comment: With this: IPaddress:port/nameofproject all the browsers say: "can't connect to the server" In the mac that I have the Acquia Dev Desktop with the Drupal inside I can access to different Drupal webs with http://nameofproject:8082/

Comment: Try without the port. IP/nameofproject. It will need to be one of the variations of that. The reason I say this, If you can get to the default page. Your just typing the url incorrectly.

Comment: I tried and doesn't work: iP/nameofproject I think I tried all the combinations possible and with different projects. What you say makes sense but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Perhaps there is something that I don't do wright

Comment: On the default page. Does it say anything like; Projects? where you can see the current project your working on?

Comment: No, I don't see projects

Comment: My projects are not Acquia Drupal. They are made in Core Drupal. Acquia is used just like a Damp, something like Mamp

Comment: In the tutorial of Lynda they recommended Acquia Drupal Desktop to create a local environment. Just a way to see core Drupal in a local server. But if it this gives so many problems could anyone recommend some other solution? Could Mamp be ok for Drupal? What do Dropal users most commonly use?

Comment: I use mamp on my work dev server and it works without any problems.

Comment: Ditto, MAMP used to work fine for me (till I got bored with rebuilding PHP for new extensions and set up a custom local stack instead). You might also want to look at [Drupal Quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding to the host file.

My mac has Acquia Dev Desktop installed.
I'm trying to access the site "example:8082" on a Windows 7 virtual machine.

I go to the virtual machine and edit the host file like this:
10.10.17.111     example

Then to access this from the Windows 7 browser, go to "http://example:8082"

Bingo, it works!